# I am trying to do a sum in a column that depends on the columns before being a 1

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 12 columns that have EITHER a '1', or '0'. I want to do a sum on the first column of all the ones. 
Then, if the first column were all '1', then I want to get the sum of all the '1' in column 2.
Then, if column 1 and 2 were all '1', then I want to get the sum of all the '1' in column 3.
and so on....
I am trying to do it with cases as below. However, it works fine, only until column 3, after column 4 I get only NULL.

```
SUM (CASE WHEN MAX(B.PREVIOUS_1) = 1  THEN  1  END ) TOTAL_MONTH_1,
SUM (CASE WHEN MAX(B.PREVIOUS_1) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_2) = 1  THEN 1  END )TOTAL_MONTH_2,
    SUM (CASE WHEN MAX(B.PREVIOUS_1) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_2) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_3) = 1 THEN  1  END ) TOTAL_MONTH_3,
    SUM (CASE WHEN MAX(B.PREVIOUS_1) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_2) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_3) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_4) = 1 THEN  1  END ) TOTAL_MONTH_4,
    SUM (CASE WHEN MAX(B.PREVIOUS_1) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_2) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_3) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_4) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_5) = 1 THEN  1  END ) TOTAL_MONTH_5
```

I expect to get

```
column 1   column 2   column 3....... 
1            1        0
0            1        1
1            0        0
```

result:

```
2            1        0
```

Comment: when you say --"if the first column were all '1', then I want to get the sum of all the '1' in column 2" ..does it mean, all the values in first column should be 1 and no zeroes should exist?

Comment: Hi! I tried to show in the "I expect to get" example, but the result didn't show up in the right place under each column. See that the sum for column 2 is = 1, since it only sums its 1s, when column 1 has a 1

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I have to admit, this question intrigued me!  I'm answering because I hate the idea of a SQL query whose text length is based on the *square* of the number of columns.  Because, honestly, you're going to have 72 case statements if you've got 12 columns (12 * 12 / 2).  That sort of code is horrible to maintain and horrible to modify.

So, I'm going to approach this like a math puzzle.  Lets say there are only two columns: a and b.  If a=0, the answer is 0; if a=1, the answer is 1 if b=0, and 2 if b=1.  Well, that's pretty straight forward: the answer is: a*(a+b).  If a=0, you're multiplying some number by 0, which will be zero.

Or we can even be fancier - we can say it's a * (1+b) - either way works, and this way, we only have a single 'a' in the picture.

```
Answer(a,b) = a*(1+b)
```

Okay, but what about a third column?

Now we have a, b, and c.  If a = 0, our answer is still zero.  But if a = 1, our answer should be 1 + Answer(b,c).

```
Answer(a,b,c) = a*(1+Answer(b,c))
Answer(a,b,c) = a*(1+b*(1+c)
```

Does that make sense?  And now that we know that, the pattern is pretty obvious:

```
Answer(a,b,c,d,....) = a*(1+b*(1+c*(1+d* ...
```

Okay - so how are we looking in terms of length?  Each term - each column - is only used *once*.  If you've got 12 columns, you're only going to have 12 terms!  Not 72!  (Plus, it's pretty easy to expand this to include another few columns.)

Better yet, it's really easy to get *sums* of each 'column' at that point.  After all, your data would look like:

```
ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD,KevinsAnswer
0    1    0    0    0
1    1    0    1    2
1    1    1    1    4
0    0    1    0    0
1    0    0    0    1
1    1    1    0    3
```

If you want to know how many rows had at least two 1's?  Get the sum() where KevinsAnswer >= 2.

So my final answer would be something like this (I apologize if there are any non-oracle commands in here; my expertise is MS SQL)

```
select StraightMonths,Count(*) from
(
    select B.PREVIOUS_1 *
        (1 + B.PREVIOUS_2 *
        (1 + B.PREVIOUS_3 *
        (1 + B.PREVIOUS_4 *
        (1 + B.PREVIOUS_5 *
        (1 + B.PREVIOUS_6 *
        (1 + B.PREVIOUS_7 *
        (1 + B.PREVIOUS_8 *
        (1 + B.PREVIOUS_9 *
        (1 + B.PREVIOUS_10 *
        (1 + B.PREVIOUS_11 *
        (1 + B.PREVIOUS_12 ))))))))))) as StraightMonths
    ) as straightMonthsSubquery
) group by StraightMonths
```

... and then using *that* as a subquery to get a specific month you're interested in; just remember, if you want month=2, you have to SUM() the values for StraightMonths >= 2 (the value in the 2 entry is just the ones that had *exactly* two months.)  Or even just put that data from the query into a temp/variable table (it's only got 12 rows with one column.)

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I love math too and I will use this one for other cases I get.

Answer (score 1):

Because CASE works as a fallthrough, you could do something like the following:

```
select CASE when column1=0 then 0
            when column2=0 then 1
            when column3=0 then 2
            when column4=0 then 3
            ...
            when column12=0 then 11
            else 12
        END as ONES_COUNT
```

This would work because you only have the binary option for each column - it can either be 1 or 0.  If it's 0, then you should stop counting and return the previous value.  If it's 1, you should fall through to the next case and repeat until you get the value.

Comment: Nice approach!  This is probably a better idea than my approach, simply because mine will fail if the assumption "All values are 0 or 1" is broken.  Excellent idea  :-)

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine, you just need to add else 0 in the all the case statements, also since you are comparing on a single observation basis, so I think MAX is not necessary, rather just compare the columns as below:

```
   sum(column1) as total_month_1,
   sum(case when column1=1 and column2=1 then 1 else 0 end) total_month_2,
   sum(case when column1=1 and column2=1 and column3=1 then 1 else 0 end) total_month_3
   sum(case when column1=1 and column2=1 and column3=1 and column4=1 then 1 else 0 end) total_month_4
   sum(case when column1=1 and column2=1 and column3=1 and column4=1 and column5=1 then 1 else 0 end) total_month_5
```

Comment: Exactly! I added the 'ELSE 0' to all columns and now it is working. Thanks so much

Comment: great, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

I would use `least()` with `sum()`:

```
select sum(col1),
       sum(least(col1, col2)),
       sum(least(col1, col2, col3)),
       . . .
from t;
```

Another method:

```
select sum(case when pos <= 1 then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when pos <= 2 then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when pos <= 3 then 1 else 0 end),
       . . .
from (select t.*,
             instr(col1 || col2 || col3 . . . || '0', '0') as pos
      from t
     ) t;
```

This calculates the position of the first `0` in each row and uses that for the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I got and it worked. BTW, the reason for the MAX, is because it comes from a result in a sub query.

```
SUM (CASE WHEN MAX(B.PREVIOUS_1) = 1  THEN  1  ELSE 0 END ) TOTAL_MONTH_1,
    SUM (CASE WHEN MAX(B.PREVIOUS_1) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_2) = 1  THEN 1  ELSE 0 END )TOTAL_MONTH_2,
    SUM (CASE WHEN MAX(B.PREVIOUS_1) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_2) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_3) = 1 THEN  1  ELSE 0 END ) TOTAL_MONTH_3,
    SUM (CASE WHEN MAX(B.PREVIOUS_1) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_2) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_3) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_4) = 1 THEN  1  ELSE 0 END ) TOTAL_MONTH_4,
    SUM (CASE WHEN MAX(B.PREVIOUS_1) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_2) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_3) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_4) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_5) = 1 THEN  1 ELSE 0   END ) TOTAL_MONTH_5,
    SUM (CASE WHEN MAX(B.PREVIOUS_1) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_2) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_3) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_4) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_5) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_6) = 1 THEN  1 ELSE 0   END ) TOTAL_MONTH_6,
    SUM (CASE WHEN MAX(B.PREVIOUS_1) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_2) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_3) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_4) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_5) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_6) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_7) = 1  THEN  1 ELSE 0   END ) TOTAL_MONTH_7,
    SUM (CASE WHEN MAX(B.PREVIOUS_1) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_2) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_3) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_4) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_5) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_6) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_7) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_8) = 1 THEN  1 ELSE 0   END ) TOTAL_MONTH_8,
    SUM (CASE WHEN MAX(B.PREVIOUS_1) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_2) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_3) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_4) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_5) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_6) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_7) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_8) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_9) = 1 THEN  1 ELSE 0   END ) TOTAL_MONTH_9,
    SUM (CASE WHEN MAX(B.PREVIOUS_1) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_2) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_3) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_4) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_5) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_6) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_7) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_8) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_9) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_10) = 1 THEN  1 ELSE 0   END ) TOTAL_MONTH_10,
    SUM (CASE WHEN MAX(B.PREVIOUS_1) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_2) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_3) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_4) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_5) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_6) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_7) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_8) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_9) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_10) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_11) = 1 THEN  1 ELSE 0   END ) TOTAL_MONTH_11,
    SUM (CASE WHEN MAX(B.PREVIOUS_1) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_2) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_3) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_4) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_5) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_6) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_7) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_8) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_9) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_10) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_11) = 1 AND  MAX(B.PREVIOUS_12) = 1 THEN  1 ELSE 0   END ) TOTAL_MONTH_12
```